# Where is the source for /usr/bin/lock?

Tags: macos, locking, terminal, gnu-screen, tmux

I have a Mac with snow leopard. I often work off the terminal using tmux (or GNU screen) When I walk away I remote ssh back to my computer. The thing is sometimes I have to step away from the computer for a minute or two. When that happens I don't want people to glance over and have access to my command line and I also don't think it is worth the whole CTRL-a,d,exit,open terminal, ssh to machine, tmux attach each time that happens.

Screen offered a CTRL-a,x that locked the screen (provided I enter in a password at least once that session because it won't read the system password) or in tmux (preferred) a clock feature.

All the documentation points to the fact that the multiplexers look for /usr/bin/lock or /usr/bin/lck. Since that is a low level utility found on linux and BSD systems where can I find the source so I can port it to Mac OS X?

Comment: I´m not sure what you´re asking for - entering ctrl-a,x works perfectly in screen on a Mac, why do you want to port lock?
Also, using your screensaver with a hot corner to activate might be faster & more secure

Comment: Two issues. screen on mac asks for a password instead of using the system password (mild annoyance) but truthfully I use tmux which is dependent on an external program for ctrl-b,x to work. The screen saver is good but will only work when I'm sitting at the computer. Usually it is locked but I'm accessing it from another computer. That's where a quick lock via tmux or ssh would be more convenient then the usual logout log back in setup.

Comment: Re: "All the documentation points to...", do you have any links to this documentation?

Comment: I was referring to the TMUX and Screen documentation (man pages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tmux* comes from OpenBSD; you can view its *lock* through [OpenBSD CVSweb for `src/usr.bin/lock/`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/lock/).

Mac OS X is more closely related to FreeBSD; you can view its *lock* code through [FreeBSD SVN ViewVC for `head/usr.bin/lock/`](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/lock/) (CVS and Perforce are also available).

Either one will require modification to even compile on Mac OS X.

A major functionality difference will be in the authentication method for the `-p` option (“use login password/authentication”): the OpenBSD code uses its own authentication system, and FreeBSD uses *crypt(3)* which will not work for most Mac OS X accounts.

Answer (score 0):

man -P "less -p lock" tmux, press n until satisfied with results?