# tmux on OSX - lock server/session not working

Tags: macos, locking, tmux

I am on OSX Mountain Lion. I've configured tmux.conf to lock the screen, but the screen only flashes, no locking takes place. (fyi, when i used GNU-screen, the screen did lock).

My system does not have a lock/slock or vlock, nor could i find these on homebrew or macports. I understand that Screen uses its own internal locking whereas tmux uses external locking. I do not care whether I am asked to enter a new passkey or the system password is used.  So how to get tmux to lock the session/terminal ?

```
# Screen lock
bind-key C-x    lock-server
bind-key x      lock-server
bind-key -n M-x lock-server
set-option -g   lock-after-time 0
set-option -g   lock-server on
# set-option -g   lock-command "vlock"
```

p.s. I am aware of other alternatives, but these typically require a mouse (hot corners) or a Mac keyboard (eject key).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, OS X does not supply any variation of the tty-locking program that *tmux* requires.

You will probably need to find a third-party tty-locking program, try [to port one from a related OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4891791/193688), or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer as you expected. @chris-johnsen gave the best answer about locking on OSX. I did however find two screen savers for the terminal. It doesn't *lock* the terminal but it does blank out the screen.

1. tmux has a built in time function that will blank the screen and display a clock. It is local to the window.
2. [`cmatrix`](http://www.asty.org/cmatrix/) is a terminal program that displays the matrix screen like in the movie. The con is that it doesn't lock and it eats up some CPU. But it is fun. It can be installed via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Here is how to get it working:

```
brew install cmatrix
```

Then add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g lock-command "cmatrix -s -b"
set -g lock-after-time 90
set -g lock-server on
```

In 90 seconds of inactivity it will display. Use the command `tmux lock-server` to test it.

Comment: CPU usage can be helped using `nice -n 20 cmatrix -s -b`

Answer (score 0):

I was disappointed to not see any valid responses for actually locking the screen. I'll continue looking for a way to properly lock the terminal session itself, but in the meantime I do have a functional alternative.

By running a command on the command line, you can lock your entire mac. The following command will make it happen:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

You can find a lot more about what's happening exactly at [this page](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/30/lock-mac-desktop-command-line/).

Tie that command into:

```
set-option -g lock-command
```

And you should have a way to functionally lock up your session. I know locking the entire machine is not the most desirable outcome, but this is at least a working alternative for now.